# problem not showing list on tab click, call new activity "openingtoday"

Tags: android

hello when i click tab then my below class named  "openingtoday" fire and i want to load data in list view after xml parsing done,my problem is that when i click tab parsing is done by calling    new ProgressTask6().execute(); in oncreate() but item is not showing in list view but when i go back and load again then it display list on tab click means load data on second time when i go back ,i think problem is becoz of i make task asynchronous on tab click ..,i make asynchronous bcoz data showing in list view was taking time but now after making it asynchronous it not run  MyAdapter class in oncreate() why??pls thanks alot

my code is below..after clicking tab this class fire..

```
    public class OpeningToday extends ListActivity {
    String name = null;
    String typename = null;
    static String array_type[];
    static int totalartist;
    static String array_galleryname[]=null;
    static String array_address[]=null;
    static String array_galleryurl[]=null;
    static String array_email[];
    static String array_web[];
    static String array_phone[];
    static String array_latitude[];
    static String array_longitude[];
    SitesList2 sitesList;
    static String gallerynames=null;
    static String addresses=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i found a little bit mistake in your code due this problem come it is .

You should set you adapter inside the dialog.onDismiss event like

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)        {

     setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
      }
     });
```

Then you find solution of your problem.
I hope this is help.

Comment: its force close on line  dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener()

Comment: 06-29 14:29:57.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(265): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 14:29:57.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(265):     at com.androidpeople.tab.OpeningToday.onCreate(OpeningToday.java:202)